# How do push notifications on the iPhone determine which users are notified?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, push-notification

I'm just trying to understand push notification more.

Let's say I have a web service that my app connects to that needs a user to sign in with a username and password. And this all works fine when running the app.

Now... how does the web service determine which user to send the push notification to?

I'm really unsure on how it works with users with usernames and passwords. It would be great if someone could enlighten me to this. A better understanding could improve my apps in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll give a brief over view of how push notifications work:

First, your app will call the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method. This will check that your app is allowed to send and receive the types of notifications you requested, and contact Apple's servers to register your device. You will get back a special token used to uniquely identify the device.

Your app needs to send this token to your server along with the details of the account that the user is logged in with, so your server can associate that token with the user.

When you want to send a push notification to a user, you lookup the token you received previously for that user and use that when sending the notification to Apple's server. This will forward the notification to the appropriate device.

It's probably a good idea if you read the Apple documentation here: [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9). This will give you a clearer understand of how it all works.

Comment: Have you got any examples of this? As I would like to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the wonderful tutorial explains in detail, http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 2):

For login procedures, you don't even need push notifications. If you need a general introduction, you will find one [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)

Answer (score 2):

Below I have mentioned 2 links.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Now coming to your question, push notification is pushed from a server. Now for a particular user the server side should maintain the database such that whatever changes made to a specific user should be pushed to that device id.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Push notification is awesome feature of iOS apps. It works like your application needs to register for Push notification as

```
//Your application registeres for push notification using following line
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

This will tells you application to handle generation of device token failure/success by delegate methods

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
     //Your application registered for push notification i.e. allowed by user.
     //You need to take device token and pass it to your webservice and store it in database.
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
     //Your application registered for push notification i.e. not allowed by user.
}
```

So, Now what after you have device token ? .. Its simple now use it for sending push notification. You can find different code for that using PHP as well as .Net. Search around and you will get plenty of them.